# Walking through an SQLite Table

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, select

I would like to implement or use functionality that allows stepping through a Table in SQLite.

If I have a Table `Products` that has 100k rows, I would like to retrive perhaps 10k rows at a time.  Somthing similar to how a webpage would list data and have a `< Previous .. Next >` link to walk through the data.

Are there select statements that can make this simple?  I see and have tried using the ROWID in conjunction with LIMIT which seems ok if not ordering the data.

// This seems works if not ordering.

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ROWID BETWEEN x AND y;
```

Comment: And what happens if you order the rows?

Comment: the ROWID if not specified explicitly is still available but is not garunteed to be static.  That said, the implicit ROWID will be determined by the order the rows are physically written in the table.  So if the table was stored in order by Name, and I want to order by QTY, the ROWID will not represent the returned order but the implicit ROW number.

Comment: You really should avoid using any built-in ROWID as much as possible in SQL work.  It isn't really part of the SQL standard, it's an add-on that isn't guaranteed to be there on most RDBMSes.  I'd use an ORDER BY clause to create an ordering instead.  I've found that most queries can be written without relying on an implicit row number, with a little bit of imagination.

Comment: Do you need to order the rows?  It doesn't sound like you would have to.  If you used SB's answer, you could just go by whatever ordering SQLite returns the data in by default.

Comment: @sheepsimulator: I agree, I have never used it in the past (As creating an explicit would be prefered if it were nessesary).  I could not think of a way to access a specific range of rows any other way however.  The LIMIT+OFFSET does this perfectly though, I just didn't realize it was available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for [offset and limit](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm)?  SQLite supports these.  You can then use [order by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp), which SQLite also supports.
**EDIT:** To elaborate, you can do something like:

`Select * from Products order by name limit 10000 offset 10000;`


This fetches the second 10k page from the table, sorted by name.  Watch out for performance issues when dealing with limit/offset and order by.

Comment: You'd use this query in your code, and make the value passed into offset a parameterized value that you increment by 10k for each chunk of records you need.